# Validate that string is string and number is number

Tags: java, postman

I want to validate string and number.
If I expect to receive an only string from JSON and receive a number I will return a message with an error. With number the same.
Can I find annotation for this?
Example @String - if I send a request from the postman without "example" and only 1 (only number)

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    //Example @String
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String name;

}
```

I create a field String in an entity. If I send from Postman 1 without "" - it isn`t correct. But if I send "1" - it correct. How it validate?
Vice versa with numbers...

I use string field, but if I send without "" - it also correct. It should be correct only with "".
How can I fix it?
From postman:
[image]

Comment: do understand that "12345" is in fact a valid String. You can create an annotation that checks that.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I thought, I can find it from javax)

Comment: hi, classic instanceof check will solve your case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate number string as digit with hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537664/how-to-validate-number-string-as-digit-with-hibernate)

Comment: It isn't duplicate

Answer (score 0):

use @NotBlank from javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank for strings
and @Digits for numbers

Comment: @NotBlank doesn't check it. I sent a number and it was saved correctly.

Comment: then use @Pattern to check using regex

Comment: Added an example with postman