# Is there a bean validation annotation for checking if the data in a string field is a number?

Tags: java, hibernate, bean-validation

I want to test whether the data in the form field is a number using [Java Bean Validation](https://beanvalidation.org).

The following example tests the size but it can still accept letters:

```java
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 5, message = "must be 5 digits or less")
@Column(name = "code")
private String code;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate number string as digit with hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537664/how-to-validate-number-string-as-digit-with-hibernate)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, actually there are several:

`@Digits(integer=6, fraction=2)`: The value of the field or property must be a number within a specified range. The integer element specifies the maximum integral digits for the number, and the fraction element specifies the maximum fractional digits for the number.

`@DecimalMax("30.00")` or `@DecimalMin("5.00")`: The value of the field must be greater or equal/lower or equal to the value specified in the annotation.

`@Min("10")` or `@Max("10")`: Same as @Decimal, but the value of the field must be an integer.

Also, if none of these are good for your needs, you can use `@Pattern` with a regex.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/bean-validation001.htm

Comment: i thought the Digits DecimalMax DecimalMin Min() Max() annotations could only be used for numeric type variables?

Comment: They can be used to validate `String` type variables as well.

Comment: @GreyWolf18 — According to the Javadocs, [`@DecimalMax`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/validation/constraints/decimalmax) supports `String` (and other `CharSequence`) values, but [`@Max`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/validation/constraints/max) does not.  Likewise for the "min" variations of these two annotations.  Hibernate Validator does extend `@Min` & `@Max` to `CharSequence` types: [guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/6.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-defineconstraints-spec), however.